# Adding elements to array list - Java

Tags: java, json, arraylist

I have a class file

```
public class Name {
    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

This is the test file

```
CollectionType javaType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, Name.class);
ArrayList<Names> nameList = mapper.readValue(json, javaType);
for (Names nameValue : nameList) {
    List<String> id = new ArrayList<>();
    id.add(nameValue.getId());
System.out.println(id);
```

json

```
[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"}]
```

In the JSON output there is more than one id, and I am trying to store them in one list but it only adds the first one ("1"), how do I store both in one list. Please help

Comment: Where are you closing the `for` loop? Your identation doesn't help too much to figure it out. In every iteration you're creating a new `List`, take the `id` outside the `for` loop

Comment: you should construct your List outside of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you iterate over the list of names, and inside the for loop you create a new `ArrayList` during every iteration! You want to create your `ArrayList` outside of the loop:

```
CollectionType javaType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, Name.class);
ArrayList<Names> nameList = mapper.readValue(json, javaType);
List<String> id = new ArrayList<>();
for (Names nameValue : nameList) {
    id.add(nameValue.getId());
}
System.out.println(id);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. Is there a way to just print the last list without printing it twice as [1], [1,2]

Comment: Actually got it, just moved the println from for loop, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration of the loop is creating a new `id` list. Declare that list outside of the loop and it will add the elements to it.